# What was the salary of high ranking Roman government officials during the Principate?

Tags: ancient-rome, government

During the Roman Principate, the Roman Empire was divided into two parts: Senatorial Provinces and Imperial Provinces. Senatorial Provinces were governed by propraetors and proconsuls, who received no salary but received a portion of the tax revenue. Imperial provinces were governed by *legatus augusti pro praetore* or *procuratores augusti*, or in the case of Egypt, by a *praefectus augusti*. These were usually members of the equestrian order.

Equestrian's in government service where divided into three ranks: *Vir Egregii*, *Vir Prefectissimo*, and *Vir Emminentissimo*. *Vir Egregii* where further subdivided by salary into *sexagenarii*, *centenarii*, *ducenarii*, and *trecenarii*. *procuratores augusti* were members of the *Vir Egregii*, as were *praefectus classis*.

My questions are as follows:

1. What rank where the *legatus augusti pro praetore*? What rank was the *praefectus Aegypt*?
2. What was the salary of *Vir Prefectissimo*? What was the salary of *Vir Emminentissimo*?
3. What other government officials of each rank where there?
4. What were the salaries and ranks of *praefectus cohorti*, *tribunus militum*, and *praefectus alae*?

Comment: Zero - excpt when they received a percentage of taxes collected. Roman nobility financed the state; not the other way around.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Equestrians were almost never Roman nobility (=descendants of consuls) especially as the emperor employed them in imperial provinces like Egypt specifically to keep senators out.  In fact many of them were foreign.  They pursued the career for a reason.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens That is not always true. Government officials of the equites in the egregii where paid according to their rank: 60,000 sesterces for sexagenarii, 100,000 sesterces for centenarii, 200,000 sesterces for ducenariii, and 300,000 sesterces for trecenarii. This still leaves open the question of the pay of those officials of rank vir prefectissimo and vir emminentissimo, which was the point of this question. The question *was not* about the pay of Roman magistrates, or about the pay of propraetors or proconsuls.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Unless you meant to say that the legatus augusti pro praetore where not paid. Otherwise this doesn’t really answer any of my questions.